# Countdown displaying elements from an array. setInterval doesn't cause a delay. The last element is displayed instantenously

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner. I'd like to create a simple countdown from an array started by a button event listener. I want to display the elements of the array after a delay in p class="countdownDisplay". However, it doesn't work the way I want. There's no delay.

```
  <p class="countdownDisplay"></p>
    <button>Start</button>
```

```
  let countdown = ["5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "Time's up!"];

  let btn = document.querySelector("button");

  let countdownDisplay = document.querySelector(".countdownDisplay");

  btn.addEventListener("click", countdownFunction);

  function countdownFunction() {
    for (let i = 0; i < countdown.length; i++) {
    countdownDisplay.innerText = countdown[i];
    console.log(countdown[i]);
    }
 }

  setInterval(countdownFunction, 5000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call the for loop, it will add from 0 until 5 at once and your code will not work. I hope the commented code below helps you:

```
let countdown = ["5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "Time's up!"];

    let btn = document.querySelector("button");

    let countdownDisplay = document.querySelector(".countdownDisplay");

    //declaring interval outside the function because we need to stop it at the end of counting
    let interval

    const startInterval = () => {
        interval = setInterval(countdownFunction, 1000);
    }

    btn.addEventListener("click", startInterval);

    //declaring the innitial value (first position of the array)
    let i = 0

    function countdownFunction() {
        countdownDisplay.innerText = countdown[i++];
        //if i is the last element of the array, stop the counting
        if(i==countdown.length)
           clearTimeout(interval)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Remove "for" loop from `countdownFunction()`.

```
let countdown = ["5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "Time's up!"];

let i= 0;

function countdownFunction() {
  console.log(countdown[i])
  ++i;
}

setInterval(countdownFunction, 5000);
```

Comment: It looks like i will advance out of bounds of the array

Comment: You're a genius :); Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but here is a solution with setTimeout. the advantage with this version, it ends after the countdown and does not continue like with setInterval.

```js
const countdown = ["5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "Time's up!"];
const countdownDisplay = document.querySelector(".countdownDisplay");
const button = document.querySelector("button");

function countdownFunction(i) {
  let _i = i++;
  setTimeout(() => {    
    console.log(countdown[_i])
    countdownDisplay.innerText = countdown[_i];    
  }, 1000 * _i, countdown[_i]);
}

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for(let i = 0; i<countdown.length; i++) {  
    countdownFunction(i)  
  }  
});
```

```html
  <p class="countdownDisplay">Click</p>
  <button>Start</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Maik for help. Am I right that setTimeout works only ONCE and setInterval starts REPEATEDLY? Is that why Elson included clearTimeout(interval) at the end?

Comment: @TomDev I think that's a mistake. Because he's not using a timeout, he's using an interval. It should then be called clearInterval().

Comment: @TomDev I added the view part in my code above.